# How can I match Korean characters in a Ruby regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, ruby-1.9, cjk

I have some basic validations for usernames using regular expressions, something like `[\w-_]+`, and I want to add support for Korean alphabet, while still keeping the validation the same.

I don't want to allow special characters, such as `{}[]!@#$%^&*()` etc., I just want to replace the `\w` with something that matches a given alphabet in addition to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Which means username like `안녕` should be valid, but not `안녕[]`.

I need to do this in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test for invalid characters like this:

```
#encoding: utf-8
def valid_name?(name)
  !name.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\p{Hangul}]/)
end

ar = %w(안녕 name 안녕[].)
ar.each{|name| puts "#{name} is #{valid_name?(name) ? "valid" : "invalid"}."}
# 안녕 is valid.
# name is valid.
# 안녕[]. is invalid.
```

Comment: See below - you should extend your regex to /[^a-zA-Z0-9\p{Hangul}\p{Han}]/ in order to also capture names like 姓. Also, this regex still doesn't support names with dashes in them, like So-Young Kim.

Comment: The question asks for Korean character/alphabet. Korean names with Chinese characters is new for me. But the OP refers to usernames, not real names, and I guess he is setting the rules.

Comment: \p{Han} is common to Korean, Japanese and Chinese. Almost all Korean names used to be written in Hanja and they are still common on business cards. They are less common on the net, but it is bad for business to tell people that their passport name is not a valid name. See also http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Sprachprofi I liked the link; also 23780f''asdf[qwerioafbh 's comment.

Comment: @Sprachprofi no, hanja is not commonly used to write names in korean... 저는샘이다.

Answer (score 20):

try this:

[가-힣]+

This matches every character from [U+AC00 to U+D7A3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Hangul_Syllables), which is probably enough for your interest. (I don't think you'll need old hangul characters and stuff)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can replace `\w` by `[:word:]`

`/^[[:word:]\-_]+$/` should work

Comment: However, that would match ALL word characters.

Answer (score 0):

Matching for invalid characters is your best option, because there are way too many valid Korean characters - it's technically an alphabet but computerized as one-character-per-syllable, and additionally there are thousands of Chinese loan characters (Hanja) which should also be valid.

Comment: The list is finite and easily matched. And \p{Hangul} is a valid regex block

Comment: \p{Hangul} does not capture Hanja, yet Hanja are still commonly used to write names. At the very least you have to check for both \p{Hangul} and \p{Han}.

Comment: Unfortunately Chinese characters are almost never used anymore in Korean, even when stating names...

Comment: Do you really want to exclude some genuine Korean customers just because they have a traditional name? The use of Hanja is always downplayed to foreigners, but if you go to a conference in Korea, a lot of the business cards still feature Hanja.

Comment: Business cards is probably the last place (with ID cards) where you see Chinese characters (and I have thousands of them that don't show any Chinese anymore). I have spent the last 25 years, 15 of which spent in Korea, watching Chinese characters disappear. Sadly nobody uses Chinese characters -- especially online...