# regular expression to remove unwanted text from string

Tags: regex, sed, cut

I am trying to extract only few information from a big string like

```
[[["좋은","good","joh-eun",""]],[["adjective",[["좋은",["good","nice","pretty","admirable","canny","tenacious"],,0.38553435]],"good",4],["adverb",["훌륭하게",["wonderfully","good","nicely","beautifully","fine","finely"],,0.00029145498],"good",4]]]
```

i want to extract the string like this

```
좋은 - good
좋은 - good,nice,pretty,admirable,canny,tenacious (basically adjectives)
훌륭하게 - wonderfully,good,nicely,beautifully,fine,finely (adverbs)
```

please help i tried using sed and pipe to cut like

```
cut --delimiter='"' -f 1-2 and then use sed 's/\[\[\[\"//'
```

This is giving me first korean **좋은** as result, i am not able to extend this to get desired result!
If there is any other better way to achieve this, please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the exemple your real input ? The formating for [] seems incoherent...

Comment: Can you distinguish what you want to "extract" from what you want to discard more precisely? (computers (or us) can't do anything with "basically").  If you can't - if you want to include all adverbs and/or adjectives, then we'll need to ponder dictionary-based solutions

Comment: @Tensibai - Its short version of actual input..have missed brackets i guess, ll edit once i get access to computer(on phone now)

Comment: @drewmoore - I want to take out verb, noun etc and its korean word from that Particular input.

Comment: My bad, once formatted the pearing is correct, I did missed a part at first. Am I right thinking adjective and advers won't be always the case and that they are optionnals ? (Not sure how to handle that with a regex, but @avinash-raj is the best regex writter I know ;) If its handlable, he can write it ;)

Comment: @Tensibai - yes adverb,verb noun or adjectives depends on input. I was guessing if we can search for words like noun, verb etc and then do regex match to fetch words inside that particular brackets.

Comment: Well if the format are different it could be a ORed regex `(?:regex verb |  regex noun | regex adverb)` But the subsitution would be hardest if there's not the same number of field for each... A larger input would be great

Comment: @Tensibai-ll update question with full input soon. Format is mostly different, depends on if a word has verb form or noun form or other forms.

Comment: I would say that as long as you don't mind having blank line at output, adapting the regex on a ORed one for each type would work. Maybe you'll have to make a second pass to suppress double blonk lines for formatting...

Comment: @Tensibai : Decided to change the output a bit like this.....좋은-good ,nice,pretty...,wonderfully,beautifully...etc(all verbs, nouns etc )..Used Java replaceall with simple Regex to get that.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but in pure regex suitable for sed:

regex: `\[\[\["(.*?)","(.*?)"\]\],\[\["(.*?)",\[\["(.*?)",\["(.*?)"\],.*?\]\],.*?\],\["(.*?)",\["(.*?)",\["(.*)"\],.*\]\]\]`

Substitution: `\1 - \2\n\4 - \5 (\3)\n\7 - \8 (\6)`

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO1lA0/1)

Assuming there's always adjectives and adverbs brackets in the orignal line... (even if empty)

See the substitution in demo to how to reorg the matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of ruby, but probably any PCRE-equipped tool can do something similar:

```
ruby -ne '
    $_.gsub(/"/,"")
      .scan(/ (\p{Hangul}+) ,\[? (.+?) \] /x) {|m| puts m[0] + " - " + m[1]}
' <<END
[[["좋은","good","joh-eun",""]],[["adjective",[["좋은",["good","nice","pretty","admirable","canny","tenacious"],,0.38553435]],"good",4],["adverb",["훌륭하게",["wonderfully","good","nicely","beautifully","fine","finely"],,0.00029145498],"good",4]]]
END
```

```
좋은 - good,joh-eun,
좋은 - good,nice,pretty,admirable,canny,tenacious
훌륭하게 - wonderfully,good,nicely,beautifully,fine,finely
```

Too bad the original text isn't in easier to handle JSON.

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10139996/7552) for how to match Korean characters.

Comment: thnx,i don't have knowledge on ruby, ll check and get back to U.